# Load all models in one line laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 20 to 25 models in my project, so when I want to use a model I have to load it in controller like

```
use App\Library;
use App\Vote;
```

Is there any better way to load a group of model.

Comment: I use an IDE (phpstorm with the laravel plugin) that does this for me without much extra effort

Comment: I want some thing by which I can load all the models inside app folder. Since some time I forget to add a model or if the line gets deleted.

Comment: maybe you are better off having this part of the code as an include file, common to all controllers, so maintenance is less.

Comment: You have to put the `use` statement wherever you want to use your model, that is the only way for the autoloader to reconize the Full Qualify name of the file corresponding to each model which must be include. **It's a must**, and it not a best pratice to put all that in a separate file and require it on top of each file,

Comment: In PHP 7, you can use `use App\{Library, Vote};`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir your code worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 7+, you can group classes with the same namespace ([documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)):

```
use App\{Library, Vote};
```